# Gap issue in my table

Tags: tables

I am writing a table in LaTeX. However, there seems to be an issue where the left is doing perfectly well but the right side has a gap above the main stuff. I did not use headers or footers. Instead, I used the `multicolumn{}{}{}` for my header. Here's what it kind of looked like:

```
                    ___________________________________________
                    ___________________________________________
                   ||                  Something              ||
                   ||_________________________________________||
                   ||                                                 <-- GAP!!!
                   ||
                   ||       Item #1             Item #2       ||
                   ||       Item #3             Item #4       ||
                   ||_________________________________________||
                   ||               Something else            ||
                   _____________________________________________
                   _____________________________________________
```

The table's more private, so I tried my best to replicate it.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{||l    r||}
            \hline
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{||c||}{Dummy text}\\
            \hline\\[2ex]
            Stuff & Blah blah\\
            Somethingorother & Junk text\\
            Spacefiller & Prop\\[5ex]
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{||c||}{Whatever}\\
            \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you wrote your table. Without seeing some code it is not possible to tell you what went wrong. If you don't want to share your table as it is, just replace its actual contents with some dummy text. How did you achieve the two blank lines below the horizontal line below "Something"?

Comment: I don't know. That's what I want to get rid of.

Comment: Just a wild guess: There is something like `\hline \\ \\ ` in your code. Replace that with just a `\hline`. If that does not help, please prepare a MWE.

Comment: check the number of columns and the number of ampersands(&)

Comment: As I suspected, there is a `\\ ` right after the `\hline`. To remove the gap and the white space, replace `\hline\\[2ex]` with `\hline `.

Comment: What I meant was that there was a gap in the double bar on the right side.

Comment: That gap was intentional, but the gap in the wall doesn't look right.

Comment: `\hline & \\[2ex]` might then give you what you want to achieve

Comment: You're right! Thank you!

Comment: How does adding the ampersand work anyway? Could you explain what adding the ampersand does?

Comment: Well, after the `\hline` a new table row starts. If you immediately add `\\ ` after that, you end the row too early (after the first column, instead of after the second column). If you end a row too early, the corrensponding vertical lines are not drawn. By adding the `&` before the `\\ ` you now move from the first empty to the second empty column and then end the row, thus the vertical line is drawn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106193/discussion-between-someone-and-leandriis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap in the double vertical line is caused by ending the row too early. Replacing `\hline \\[2ex]` with `\hline & \\[2ex]` removed this gap. Since you seem to insist on keeping the vertical white space that is introduced by this empty row, here are two versions  of your table. In the first one, I did the above mentioned change, while I used the `hhline` package in the second example in order to improve the intersections of two double lines at the corners of the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{||l    r||}
            \hline
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{||c||}{Dummy text}\\
            \hline 
            & \\[2ex] % <--- added the & here to remove gap in wirght double vertical line
            Stuff & Blah blah\\
            Somethingorother & Junk text\\
            Spacefiller & Prop\\[5ex]
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{||c||}{Whatever}\\
            \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{||l    r||}
            \hhline{|t:==:t|} % <-- replaced double \hline with appropriate \hhline from hhline package
            \multicolumn{2}{||c||}{Dummy text}\\
            \hhline{||--||} % <-- replaced  \hline with appropriate \hhline from hhline package
            & \\[2ex]
            Stuff & Blah blah\\
            Somethingorother & Junk text\\
            Spacefiller & Prop\\[5ex]
            \hhline{||--||}  % <-- replaced  \hline with appropriate \hhline from hhline package
            \multicolumn{2}{||c||}{Whatever}\\
            \hhline{|b:==:b|} % <-- replaced double \hline with appropriate \hhline from hhline package
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you extend this to triple lines or more?

Comment: I want to add a double line in the middle that forms a T-junction with the double lines on the sides. Is it possible to do that with hhline?

Comment: Nevermind. But can you make a triple line with one `\hhline{}` command? Or does it take two?

Comment: The mentioned double lines are most likely possible with `hhline` as well as the mentioned T-junction. Regarding the triple lines: I don't think this is possible that easily. Could you explain why you need triple lines in a table? Probably there is a better solution?

Comment: I figured out T-junction and triple lines though

Comment: I like the hhline package. You can do so much with it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \toprule
    \rowcolor{red!20!yellow}    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Dummy text}\\
        \midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!30}  Stuff & Blah blah\\
    \rowcolor{blue!30}  Somethingorother & Junk text\\
    \rowcolor{green!30} Spacefiller & Prop\\
        \midrule
    \rowcolor{red!20!yellow}    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Whatever}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: That's a lot of color

Comment: Does `\rowcolor` require a package? Also, could you explain `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`?

Comment: Are those similar to `\hline`s?

Comment: have a look at the package documentation--`booktabs` --self explanatory--- http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf -- and for rowcolor the colortbl package docu -- http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf